# How to pass 3 arguments to an Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to make an HTTP Get REST API that will take 3 parameters.
However, I am getting errors or the 3 parameters are not getting passed.

I get a build error - `"HttpGetAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments"`

Here is the way, I am checking it.

https://localhost:44312/api/test/1/2/3

I have removed the line HttpGet but it doesn't help.

```
[Route("api/controller/{a}/{b}/{c}")]
[HttpGet("{a}", "{b}", "{c}")]
public string Get(int a, int b, int c){
  int sum = a + b + c;
  return sum.ToString();
}
```

I expect the URL to pass these parameters to the REST GET API.

Comment: tried that but that doesn't work

Comment: The url u have used here - is my own URL

Comment: `[HttpGet("{a}/{b}/{c}")]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 changes to the routing:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]     // [controller]
[HttpGet("{a}/{b}/{c}")]        
public string Get(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int sum = a + b + c;
    return sum.ToString();
}
```

If you want to make the parameters required then you can use the `[Required]` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model).

Comment: "See attribute routing: Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2" but the question is about ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET Web API 2, that link is useless. Besides that, why would you put a Route **and** a HttpGet attribute? Route is for Controllers to set up the base route, not for Actions

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you just removed the .asp.net-webapi tag? The question and title did reference Asp.Net core WebAPI and WebAPI controller until your edit.  OP also states they're making a REST API.  Seems to fit to my interpretation. Please explain?

Comment: No, that's wrong, I removed the ASP.NET Core WebAPI tag, because ASP.NET Core Web API is not being used in the question

Comment: it works, how do I put that a, b, c are required parameters?

Comment: @PrawnHongs you can try adding the `[Required]` attribute to each parameter (`[Required] int a` ). Another option is to create a model with `[Required]` decorating the properties.